# batch script to execute sqloader

Tags: oracle, cmd, sql-loader

I need to use the sql-loader to import some data into a table.
Here is my batch-script:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("C:\Users\test\*.csv") do (
SET tmpFile=%%~ni
echo load data                                                      >controlfile.ctl
echo INFILE 'controlfile.ctl'                                               >>controlfile.ctl
echo into table TABLE_NAME                                          >>controlfile.ctl
echo append                                                         >>controlfile.ctl
echo fields terminated by ','                                       >>controlfile.ctl
echo OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'                             >>controlfile.ctl
echo trailing nullcols                                              >>controlfile.ctl
echo            (                                                   >>controlfile.ctl
echo                 COLUMN1 CHAR(4000),                                >>controlfile.ctl
echo                 COLUMN2 CHAR(4000),                            >>controlfile.ctl
echo                 COLUMN3 CHAR(4000),                                >>controlfile.ctl
echo                 FILE_NAME  %tmpFile%                           >>controlfile.ctl
echo            )                                                   >>controlfile.ctl
sqlldr db_user/db_pw CONTROL='C:\test\controlfile.ctl' LOG='C:\Users\test\mylog.log' skip=1
) 
pause
```

Normally you have a control-file and a script that executes this file, however
you cannot pass parameter to the control-file. IN my case, I want to save the fileName on the column in the table. Therefore I need to create the control-file on the fly, because on this way I can pass the fileName as a parameter (tmpFile)

However, I am stuck and cannot go further.

First, the control-file will be generated however most of the content is missing:

```
  COLUMN1 CHAR(4000
              COLUMN2 CHAR(4000),                            
              COLUMN3 CHAR(4000),
          FILE_NAME test                         
           )
```

And secondly, I get this message on my cmd:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Ignore for a moment the second part (or maybe you know exactly why I get this error)...Why is most of the content missing in my control-file? Can someone pls help me...I am stuck and don't know what to do

Comment: Yeah, I will have only 1 csv-file each day to load...my problem is that i cannot create the control-file dynamically...half of the content is missing in the file after it is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to escape the closing parentheses in the echoed texts like `^)`. Otherwise, the opening parenthesis of `for ... do (` becomes closed at an unexpected point, because the first unescaped `)` is considered as the closing one. The echoed opening ones can be escaped too (like `^(`), but it is not necessary (although I prefer it for cosmetical reasons).
2. Then do not store `%%~ni` in a variable, simply echo `%%~ni` directly later.
3. The trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> and <kbd>TABs</kbd> are also echoed and become therefore written to the file `controlfile.ctl`, unless you remove them, you change the syntax to `> "controlfile.ctl" echo Text`, or you implement the suggestion in the next item.
4. You may also place all `echo` lines in another pair of parentheses and redirect (write) this entire block once by `> "controlfile.ctl"`.

So here is the fixed code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("C:\Users\test\*.csv") do (
    > "controlfile.ctl" (
        echo load data
        echo INFILE 'controlfile.ctl'
        echo into table TABLE_NAME
        echo append
        echo fields terminated by ','
        echo OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
        echo trailing nullcols
        echo            ^(
        echo                 COLUMN1 CHAR^(4000^),
        echo                 COLUMN2 CHAR^(4000^),
        echo                 COLUMN3 CHAR^(4000^),
        echo                 FILE_NAME  %%~ni
        echo            ^)
    )
    sqlldr db_user/db_pw CONTROL='C:\test\controlfile.ctl' LOG='C:\Users\test\mylog.log' skip=1
)
pause
```